# React unexepected token on a conditional HTML link

Tags: reactjs

In `react` I am trying to display a link if one exists like this...

```
{link
    ? <a href={link}>
    : 
}

    <h2>Link Content </h2>

{link
    ? </a>
    : 
}
```

But when I try and build it I get the message...

```
Unexpected token ? </a>
```

Does anybody know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try link
    && <a href={link}>, or link
    ? <a href={link}>: null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a ternary, you need to have something on the right of the `:` to return when your case is `false`.  An easier way would be to use `&&` in this situation -

```
{link && <a href={link}>}
  <h2>Link Content </h2>
{link && </a>}
```

Which will wrap your `h2` in an `a` tag only when the link exists.

If you really want to use a ternary, you can do the following:

```
{link ? (
  <a href={link}>
    <h2>Link Content</h2>
  </a>
) : <h2>Link Content</h2>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your syntax is wrong.Example:

```
render () {
 return (
    <div className="row">
      { //Check if message failed
        (this.state.message === 'failed')
          ? <div> Something went wrong </div> 
          : <div> Everything in the world is fine </div> 
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```